# AngularJS views to pdf using Shrimp

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pdf

I've got a large Rails 3.2 / AngularJS app and I'm trying to create a pdf of an AngularJS view/template.

I'm using Shrimp (which creates pdfs using phantomJS) and I'm getting the template but none of the data which is created through AngularJS. This I suspect is because I'm running it outside of Rails.

When I run it as Middleware and point it to my page

```
http://localhost:3000/api#/report/1.pdf
```

AngularJS picks this up in it's routing system. So I tried

```
http://localhost:3000/api.pdf#/report/1
```

and now Shrimp times out and doesn't load the AngularJS at all.

Is Shrimp the correct too for this?

If so, how do I set it up so that it works with AngularJS templates & routing?

Is there a better tool I should be using to dynamically create a PDF from the content on the screen (ie: a lot of the calculations in the report are done in AngularJS)?

Comment: Sounds like your js code is either not running, or maybe your timeouts for rendering are too low. See rendering_timeout and rendering_time configuration fields.

Comment: I've tried playing around with the timeouts. I think the problem is when I put it as Middleware I don't know how to call it, but if I call it from outside Rails then I'm not authenticated so I cannot access the data. How do I put Shrimp in Rails but call it correctly for an AngularJS template?

Answer (score 0):

So I realise this question is old, and you have probably moved on, but perhaps this helps someone else.

I have an Ember app that I am trying to achieve a similar thing with. The key thing to realise with what is trying to be achieved here is that everything after the `#` is invisible to the server. So there is no way for the JS app to know the route that is needed to be navigated to.

I solved this problem by passing a `GET` param to the server, embedding that using the gon gem in the output html on the layout and then having something in Ember's Application route that read the property and transitioned the app to the desired route.

Now if I can just get Shrimp to render something that phantomjs from the command line can...

Comment: I just ended up putting a link directly to the pdf and using the rails routes to send a PDF back to the client. <a href="/report/{{report.id}}.pdf">Export PDF</a> This seems to work ok.

Comment: Yeah, that would work for sure. By the sounds of it there is a lot more dynamic-ness going on for us with a multitude of possibilities so we couldn't do that.

Comment: I have tried you way, by sending a get request through AngularJS to the server and I can get it to render the PDF on the Rails side, but I don't know how to send that back so that the browser will download the pdf which was just created.

Comment: are you still running the middleware approach as mentioned above? we haven't successfully used that. We pushed the pdf creation into a background worker and save it to S3 in a model using carrier wave. Since we are generating reports we want those reports to be available forever.

Comment: Yes I'm still passing this job to the backend (Rails) and letting it send the data back. It's enough for me for now.